# Why is the root partition on my disk full?

Tags: partitioning, windows, dual-boot, home-directory, disk-usage

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 by doing a fresh install where there was previously Ubuntu 11.10. My computer warns me now that my disk is nearly full. After having run `apt-get purge`, run `apt-get autoremove` and emptied the Trash can, I still have this problem as shown by this screenshot of Gparted:
[image: gparted screenshot]

The disk `/dev/sda7` is indeed full. I ran the Disk Usage Analyzer (Baobab) and I am still not sure of what is happening:
[image: baobab screenshot]

One of my hypothesis is that when installing Ubuntu 12.04, I didn't configure my disks well and the disk `/dev/sda6` is not mounted well as `/home`.
Is this the reason indeed? What should I do to verify this and then to get the things fixed?

---

Here are a few additional details to answer the questions I received (thank you everybody):

- My home directory is not encrypted.
- The Backup utility (Déjà Dup) is not set for automatic backups. (I do it myself and manually.)
- After I mount `/dev/sda6`, the command `df -h` gives

  ```
  Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
  /dev/sda7       244G  221G   12G  96% /
  udev            3,9G  4,0K  3,9G   1% /dev
  tmpfs           1,6G  904K  1,6G   1% /run
  none            5,0M     0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
  none            3,9G  164K  3,9G   1% /run/shm
  /dev/sda6       653G  189G  433G  31% /media/8ec2fa69-039b-4c52-ab1b-034d785132a1
  ```
- Thanks to izx's post, I realized `/dev/sda6` was not even mounted before. It contains all the documents I used to have when I was running Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: Drill down on the directories using the arrows on the left. That should provide some more light.

Comment: One potential gotcha I experienced is if you've set a deja-dup backup directory in Ubuntu One as 'always in sync' ‒ that can lead to a copy of your whole home directory being downloaded into your home directory, which then gets backed up and downloaded again! If you're using deja-dup and find backing up really slow see if that setting is enabled.

Comment: Whats the output of the command `df -h`? It looks like /dev/sda6 has not been mounted as /home, if that is what you intended. If this is the case it is an easy fix, but you will need to move anything you have saved in /home since installing 12.04 because you need an empty directory to mount a partition/disk there.

Comment: Is /home encrypted?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> One of my hypothesis is that when installing Ubuntu 12.04, I didn't configure my disks well and the disk `/dev/sda6` is not mounted well as `/home`. Is this the reason indeed?

*Yes!*

> What should I do to verify this

gparted clearly shows that `/dev/sda6`, although it contains some data, is NOT mounted as `/home` (or as anything).

> and then to get the things fixed?

Outline: You would temporarily mount `/dev/sda6`, clean it up (or just format it, if the existing data doesn't matter), copy everything in your `/home` to it, unmount it and then set up `/etc/fstab` to mount it as `/home` from then on. Then reboot...

### [Official Guide on moving your home directory](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving)

Please follow this [official guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving) which explains the process in more detail, and ask us any questions or concerns you may have in the comments.

---

As @jrg indicates in the comments though, if your `/home` is encrypted things get a little more complicated. Please ask a new question mentioning that in the title if you are in this situation.

Comment: I followed the guide: it is of excellent quality. All things were fine. Except three minor things that appeared when I checked if copying worked with diff: my weather indicator had updated its status, a lot of files had been updated due to Ubuntu One, and finally I had a line that reported differences: diff -r /home/agmenor/.gconf/apps/gedit-2/plugins/%gconf.xml /media/home/agmenor/.gconf/apps/gedit-2/plugins/%gconf.xml. More details here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1030963/