# Repartitioning after LVM partitioning

Tags: partitioning, lvm, umount

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 using LVM method. Now while trying to re-partition HDD using Gparted, I saw that my HDD  present situation is like this :
[image]
LVM is using the entire part of extended space. (**Also both of them are** **locked** ? why ? I did not lock those with any password or anything!!)

I searched through this forum and found another similar question [LVM Hard disk partitioning after Ubuntu installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1017945/lvm-hard-disk-partitioning-after-ubuntu-installation) and did as *pas4080* said.

While defragmenting with 
`sudo e4defrag /mnt`

I got the result

```
Success:            [ 140820/243617 ]
Failure:            [ 102797/243617 ]
```

though each of the processes showed to be 'ok'

2nd step showed : `$ umount /dev/ubuntu-vg/root`

```
umount: /mnt: umount failed: Operation not permitted
```

Now I don't know what the faliure was or why umount was not permitted. 
Can anybody help me here?

EDIT : as suggested by oldfred

```
sudo umount /dev/vg_ubuntu/lv_root
[sudo] password for alpha: 
umount: /dev/vg_ubuntu/lv_root: mountpoint not found
```

Comment: You do not use gparted with LVM. You need to use LVM tools to resize volumes. But LVM is intended to use entire drive, so if you want to create partition outside the LVM, you have to first shrink LVM inside partition and then may be able to shrink physical holding LVM. http://askubuntu.com/questions/196125/how-can-i-resize-an-lvm-partition-i-e-physical-volume

Comment: I tried to shrink LVM as suggested by the link I shared but gave me error...later I tried the command your link suggested. there too I got error. I edited my question with the error.

Comment: I do not know LVM, but most desktop installs  with LVM are also encrypted. You have to give passphrase to mount encrypted volumes for commands to work. Since this is major changes to system, you do have good backups?

Comment: Yes, I have backups. what kind of passphrase, can you help ?

Comment: Did you use the full drive install with encryption? You are then asked for a passphrase every time you boot to un-encrypt your data.

Comment: Nope I never encrypted..